# How to make a condition where the row will stop making new lines when the column reach its limit value? triangle for loop

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

How to make a condition where the row will stop making new lines when the column reach its limit value?

Expected output:

```
Enter a number: 23

1   
2 3 
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21   
22 23
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n;
    int count=1;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n );

    /*how to find the relation between row and count? when count reach its limit the row must stop executing the new line.*/
    for(int i=1 ; i<= ?? ; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j<=i; j++)
        {
            if(count<=n)
            printf("%d",count++);
        }       
            
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add code, error messages, output, ... as text not as image. Tag the question with the language tag

Comment: There is no C language in tags. only c++,phyton etc..

Comment: *here is no C language in tags.* I do not belive that. @VLL has added it 11 min. before

Comment: I think you should replace `i<= ??` by `i<= n`: if this does not behave the way to expect it to behave, you might check the interior of your for-loop.

Comment: Thats problem I want the rows will stop putting new line when the column reached it limit. I dont have any idea what condition I put to break the outer loop which responsible for the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pure C

```
int main() {
    int n = 0;                   
    int count = 0; //suppose it is a row count         
    
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n );

    for (int i = 0; i < n;)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= count; ++j, ++i)
        {
            if(i < n)
                printf("%d",i + 1);
        }
        printf("\n");
        ++count;
    }
        
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter a number: 50
1
23
456
78910
1112131415
161718192021
22232425262728
2930313233343536
373839404142434445
4647484950
```

Comment: Please don't answer a question until the poster has established what programming language that is used.

Comment: Can you translate it to nested for loop c lang..?

Comment: @JJwupee check it